# Solr query does not return expected results

Tags: java, solr, solrj

My Solr server references events, with various text fields (event name, description, keywords...) and of course begin date and end date.

When I launch the following query:

```
http://xxxxxxxxxxx/viparis-solr-server/150/spell?q=foire&wt=json
```

I get 28 events, all of them containing the word "foire" in one of the indexed text fields.

But if I lauch the following query:

```
http://xxxxxxxxxxx/viparis-solr-server/150/spell?q=foire%20%2BdateFin:[NOW%20TO%20*]&wt=json
```

I get 100 events ("dateFin" means "endDate" in french), all of them with an end date today or after today, but not all of them containing the word "foire" in one of the indexed text field.

How can I manage to combine the 2 criteria, in order to get only the events containing the word "foire" AND with an end date after today?

Comment: Query should be q=foire&fq=dateFin:[NOW TO *]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default query operator for solr is OR. You can do one of the following to get the AND behavior you are expecting:

- Add `&q.op=AND` to your request
- Place a `+` in front of your search terms to tell Solr to include them both.
- Use the finDate as a [filter query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq).

You can get more details from the [SolrQuerySyntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) page.

Comment: `http://xxxxxxxxxxx/viparis-solr-server/150/spell?q=foire%20%2BdateFin:[NOW%20TO%20*]&q.op=AND&wt=json` is not working either.

Comment: As I suggested as well as @Jayendra, try using dateFin as a fiter query.

Comment: The filter query did the job. Thank you!